# NSManagedObjects properties always nil with Quick-Nimble

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, nsmanagedobject, quick-nimble

In the past, I've tested my CoreData layer in XCTests by setting up a managed object context in memory as described in [this post](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/01/13/unit-testing-model-layer-core-data-swift/).  Basically:

```
class func setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])!
        let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

        do {
            try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Adding in-memory persistent store failed")
        }

        let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

        return managedObjectContext
    }
```

Recently I've been using Quick/Nimble with the same setup and in the `expect` statements it always reads the properties of my NSManagedObject as being nil, even though they have values when I debug the tests. For example, where `savedItem` is an NSManagedObject instance, when I store its property in a variable, it will pass:

```
let name = savedItem.name
it("should have a name") {
    expect(name).to(equal(item.name))
}
```

but if I test `savedItem.name` directly:

```
it("should have a name") {
    expect(savedItem.name).to(equal(item.name))
}
```

the test fails with the message: `expected ... got <nil>`

How can I test my CoreData objects directly using Quick/Nimble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odd behaviour I was experiencing seems to have been related to the fact that I was initializing my `NSManagedObject` *directly* inside the `context` closure but before the `it` closure.  When I initialized it in a `beforeEach` closure (inside of `context`) it behaved as expected.